# っては replaced with っちゃ？

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language, contractions

My friend said:

> うたっちゃだめだから。

Is the っちゃ a colloquial replacement for っては　in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Precisely.

In meaning,

「ては」＝「ちゃ」, 「ちゃあ」.

Thus,

> 「うたっちゃだめだから。」

means:

> "You shouldn't sing (it/this song/here/now, etc)."

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you. So for example could you say?:
すっかり食べ終わっちゃいない